# I have to click twice to initialize a sort table with Sortable.init()

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, sortables

I am using Ajax Load More to load some tables on my WordPress website. I added a sorting function to the table using a plugin called sortable.
Before loading with ajax, I can sort out the table by simply adding `data-sortable` to the table tag like this `<table class="uk-table uk-table-large" data-sortable>`.

But it stopped working once I started using ajax to load the tables.
So I tried to initialize the sorting on each table loaded via ajax using the code below:

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '.floor .uk-table', function() {
   Sortable.init()
});
```

The code seems to work but I had to click each tables' headers twice for each column to be sorted out. I am not an expert with javascript so I am not sure why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding a click event listener to the `document` you can just add it directly to the class itself.
Example:

```js
jQuery('.uk-table').click(function() {
   Sortable.init()
});
```

Comment: This code does not work because I think the tables are loaded dynamically via ajax. For this kind of click event to work with the ajax more loading plugin, the instruction is to trigger click events to make use of the jQuery .on() event handler.